# How to rewrite the particular query string in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried to rewrite the query string using hooks but cant get the right url. Should i place it in htaccess.

```
current url:    https://exmaple.com/club-contact/?officer=MzYzOU1ZX1NFQ1JFVF9TVFVGRg==
url rewritten:  https://exmaple.com/club-contact/MzYzOU1ZX1NFQ1JFVF9TVFVGRg==/officer


function custom_rewrite( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        'club-contact/(.+)'  =>  'index.php?page_id=3692&officer=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1),
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

function custom_wp_querystring() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%officer%','([^&]+)');
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_wp_querystring');
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'custom_rewrite' );
```

Comment: How is `society-contact/(.+)` supposed to match anything here, considering that none of the URLs you mentioned contained `society-contact` anywhere?

Comment: i have changed to society-contact